# Any way to handle Stream Json with RestTemplate?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflux

Is there any way to handle `application/stream+json` content with the old fashioned `RestTemplate` the way `webClient` does?

As far as my attempts go, wrapping the results of something like  `restTemplate.getForEntity` in `Flux.just(<convert response entity to mono here>)` would just return the first element and stop at that, while `webClient` handles it properly, populating that resulting json with new entries as they appear. Haven't tried working with `inputStream` yet, but at first glance it doesn't seem to be what i need, despite having a "stream" in its name.

Unfortunately, using `webClient` would be a rather costly option in this case (still waiting for https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/4921). I'd rather implement things that would "soon" appear officially only if there's absolutely no other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RestTemplate` is exposing an API which is not meant to be used to stream the HTTP response. The underlying HTTP response is read and closed after each call, whereas the `"application/stream+json"` media type is meant for streaming responses.

I don't see any way to properly handle this use case (reading streaming responses) with `RestTemplate`, by design (check out [SPR-14882](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14882) for another example of that). So you'll probably have to wait for that issue to be resolved or use another HTTP client with such features.